# aws efs and container caps to be able to run `mount nfs` inside the container manually

Tags: aws, container, kubernetes, capabilities

I'm running a pod inside aws eks 1.26. I need to mount aws efs via `kubectl exec` operation and fail if the POD is not started with privileged container.

**What priviliges are required for the container running inside aws eks to execute the `mount` command to mount aws efs?**

#### This configuration works

```yaml
securityContext:
  privileged: true
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
```

#### This configuration fails

```yaml
securityContext:
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
  privileged: false
  capabilities:
    drop:
      - all
    add:
     - NET_ADMIN
     - SYS_ADMIN
```

I'm getting the following **error**:

```bash
pod-9cff887c9-cnsk9:~$ mount -t nfs \
    -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport \
     fs-IIIIID.efs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:/ \
     ~/efs-mount-point


mount: drop permissions failed.
```

The following is the image of the container

```bash
FROM debian:latest
RUN apt update -y && apt install git nano ssh tar binutils \
    curl jq lsof make netcat nmap openssh-client rsync strace \
    sudo tcpdump telnet vim-nox wget fpart -y

# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/installing-amazon-efs-utils.html
# Here we install EFS utils for mounting whole EFS system (backup restore purposes and etc)https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/installing-amazon-efs-utils.html
RUN git clone https://github.com/aws/efs-utils && \
    cd efs-utils && \
    ./build-deb.sh && \
    apt-get -y install ./build/amazon-efs-utils*deb

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN groupadd -g 1001 deploy && \
    useradd -u 1001 -g 1001 --create-home -s /bin/bash deploy && \
    adduser deploy sudo && \
    echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers

# Add git config 
COPY ./docker/.gitconfig /root/.gitconfig
COPY ./docker/.gitconfig /home/deploy/.gitconfig
WORKDIR /home/deploy
USER deploy
```

this is my AWS EFS Info

[image]